# Understanding issue with shared pointers (Lifetime, passing as parameter)

Tags: c++11, boost-asio, shared-ptr, coredump

I tried to start with the boost asio chat example and derive an own networking program. Unfortunately I have some problem understanding what really happens. I tried to reduce my program to an absolute minimum. A server class waits for incoming connections and creates a session object to handle the connection. This is the code of the server:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session>
{
public:
    Session(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket __oSocket);
    virtual ~Session();
    void StartSession();
private:
    void StartRecv();
    std::vector<int32_t> m_vecSetupReceiveBuffer;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_oSocket;
};

Session::Session(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket __oSocket) :
    m_vecSetupReceiveBuffer({2}),
    m_oSocket(std::move(__oSocket))
{    }

Session::~Session()
{
    std::cout << "Deleted session" << std::endl;
}

void Session::StartSession()
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    std::cout << "StartSession()" << std::endl;
    boost::asio::async_write(m_oSocket, boost::asio::buffer(m_vecSetupReceiveBuffer),
    [this, self](boost::system::error_code _oError, std::size_t)
    {
        std::cout << m_vecSetupReceiveBuffer.size() << std::endl;
        StartRecv();
    });
}

void Session::StartRecv()
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    std::cout << "StartRecv()" << std::endl;
    boost::asio::async_read(m_oSocket, boost::asio::buffer(m_vecSetupReceiveBuffer),
    [this, self](boost::system::error_code _oError, std::size_t)
    {});
}

class Server
{
public:
    Server(boost::asio::io_service& _rIOService, uint32_t _nPort);
    virtual ~Server();
private:
    void StartAccept();
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor m_oAcceptor;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_oSocket;
};

Server::Server(boost::asio::io_service& _rIOService, uint32_t _nPort) :
    m_oAcceptor(_rIOService, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), _nPort)),
    m_oSocket(_rIOService)
{
    StartAccept();
}

Server::~Server()
{}

void Server::StartAccept()
{
    m_oAcceptor.async_accept(m_oSocket,
    [this](boost::system::error_code _oError)
    {
        std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(m_oSocket))->StartSession();
        StartAccept();
    });
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service _oIOServerService;
    std::shared_ptr<Server> _pServer(std::make_shared<Server>(_oIOServerService, 2000));
    _oIOServerService.run();
    return 0;
}
```

This code runs as intended, but as I tried to adjust some things and to play a little bit around I figured out that I don't understand when shared pointers are really created and deleted and where they are stored. For example I tried to change the `std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(m_oSocket))->StartSession();` to `std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(m_oSocket));` and added the `StartSession();` in the constructor of the Session class. If I run the code then, it throws

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
what():  bad_weak_ptr
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This presumably happens in `auto self(shared_from_this());`. But I don't understand why? What should I change in my code? So I think my problem is that I don't understand how to use the shared_ptr correctly, how to use it in these constructions, where I can access it and how to make it accessible. Further it is not clear why I sometimes have to user `this` and when to use `shared_from_this()`. Is there a good tutorial, or a simple rule of thumb?

It is also unclear to me, why some user the lambda function notation, and some the `boost::bind` notation and what are the differences?

So please forgive my newbie questions, I tried to find some information in tutorials but am only confused with these shared pointers and boost::asio. It seems always to do strange things.

Comment: `boost::asio` predates C++11, which is where lambdas were introduced, so people used `boost::bind`. Consistency with existing code is the only reason to use it now

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But to clarify, how would the equivalent of `boost::asio::async_write(m_oSocket, boost::asio::buffer(m_vecSetupReceiveBuffer),
[this, self](boost::system::error_code _oError, std::size_t)
{});` be?

Comment: You would need a `void Session::doNothing(std::shared_ptr<Session>) {};`, and then it would be `boost::asio::async_write(m_oSocket, boost::asio::buffer(m_vecSetupReceiveBuffer), boost::bind(&Session::doNothing, this, self));`

Comment: oops, i mean `void Session::doNothing(std::shared_ptr<Session>, boost::system::error_code _oError, std::size_t) {};`, forgot there were extra parameters

Comment: Then when `async_write` calls it, it gets `this` and `self` from the bind, and `_oError` and the unnamed `size_t` from some locals in `async_write`

Comment: Okay this explains much, in some of my trials with bind I simply replaced `this` by `shared_from_this()`, hence the shared_ptr is deleted as soon as this function returns or binds another one.
But then another question, why is it possible to replace `this` and `shared_from_this`, shouldn't the compiler complain because of `shared_from_this()` being a wrong variable type?

Comment: Iirc `bind` does some massaging of values, somewhere inside it will be doing `shared.get()` to go from `shared_ptr<Session>` to `Session *`, because that's convenient and unambiguous. It might not even need to do that, as `raw->method(args)` and `shared->method(args)` are both well-formed. Have a look at [std::invoke](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) for an idea of what is "normal" with callables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `std::bad_weak_ptr` because there is no `shared_ptr` owning `this` during the construction of your `Session`. You are still in the body of `make_shared`, and it hasn't finished creating the `shared_ptr`.

`shared_from_this()` is only available from the instance of `Session`, it is a member function. You have inherited it by deriving from `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

The lambdas are constructed with copies of `self`, and the members of `Session` are available as-if `this` also pointed to the `Session` object, not the lambda object, because of the `this` capture

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, the shared_ptr is created after the constructor of Session, which means it can therefore not use shared_from_this(). I thought in the direction of the shared_ptr beeing deleted on any reason. Thank you.
But why do I use the shared_from_this() in the Session class lambda functions but not in the server?

Comment: And is the shared_ptr moved or copied or made available on another way in the lambda function?